# How do i solve this task about the the Reservoir Sampling algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, database-theory, databases

Hello I have the following task (no homework).

> You are using the Reservoir Sampling algorithm. You process the 2000th element in the data stream and are maintaining a
>   sample of size 500. What is the probability of the first element in the sample being replaced by the current element?

My problem is, that I have no idea how to find this probability.
I know how the algorithm works but I can't solve this task.

I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: Note the question is asking you for the probability that the first element in the current *sample* is replaced by the new element. This probability is part of the *definition* of the reservoir sampling algorithm.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Hello, I believe I'm blind, or too uneducated because I do not see it. Isn't the probability random? So we can't calculate it? Is that what you want to tell me?

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the meaning of *probability*.

Comment: I'm sorry i was wrong, I just confused something. But in the definition on wikipedia I can't find what could help me here. Could you give me some more details ? Im so sorry, but I'm not that smart:(

Comment: @Yuval Filmus I think i have the answer. Could it be $\frac{1}{4}$?

Comment: The algorithm specifies the probability that the new element replaces each element in the sample. Go over the definition of the algorithm again. This is really something it's better you understood on your own.

Comment: $1/4$ is the probability that the new element gets into the sample. The probability that it replaces the first element in particular is smaller.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus Hello, I know you wont tell me the answer but I cant find the solution, I tried it now for over 6 hours. Could you give me one more hint pls pls Maybe $\frac{1}{2000}$?

Comment: You can program it and estimate the probability empirically (with smaller numbers).